# sort my display data based on their user role

Tags: php

hi i already can make search. now how i want to put that data based on their role, based on this picture i want to make admin ,admin , user, user,user. need to use sort by ? i dont know.

[image: my website]

and this my coding search . where should i put sort by ?

```
<?php
include 'config1.php';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$searchTerm = $_POST['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";
$result  = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table height = '30%'border='1'>";
if($count == 0)
  {
   echo "NO ID REGISTERED!";
  }  
else
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER ID:</b> {$row['userid']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER NAME :</b> {$row['username']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER EMAIL:</b> {$row['useremail']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER ROLE:</b> {$row['userrole']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER DIVISION:</b> {$row['userdiv']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER DEPARTMENT:</b> {$row['userdepartment']} </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo"</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: use `ORDER BY userrole` on query, and consider ditching `mysql_` functions, and replace them with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860140#12860140)

Comment: where should i put ORDER BY ?

Comment: can you give me complete coding for order by ?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ORDER BY userrole";`.... @Ghost's original response told you everything you needed to know to be able to figure it out for yourself

Comment: thanks :) do you know how to make delete button from this search . i will create one button , call delete , so when i click that button the user that i search will deleted. except admin . if i search admin , cant delete. only user. can u help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ORDER BY userrole";
```

Also can use ASC or DESC for displaying in ascending or descending order after ORDER BY.
eg.

```
Select * from users WHERE choice = 'PHP' ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: hi guys , i want to ask . i already manage to search that user details. then i create one button called delete. i want to delete that user id . and if user role is admin i cant delete them . only user. can you help me ?

Comment: DELETE FROM members where userid = $userid and userrole <> 'admin';

Comment: where should i put this delete from ? in new page that button linked to ? or under search ? and $userid declare what ? $userid = $_POST['userid'] ? should i use if(isset($_POST['delete']))?  *sorry for my bad english *

Comment: the list u shown above in that u can create dynamic delete button for each row.And on click of that you can call this query by passing userid of that row.

Comment: how to put delete button in every row? i mean when i insert user id , there are only one data display. how should i put this delete button ? can you show me the coding ? i cant imagine it. heee sorry .

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid LIKE '%$searchTerm%' order by fieldWhichYouWant";
```

**OR**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userid LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ORDER BY userrole ASC";
```

or add **ASC** or **DESC** as Ascending or descending oder to sort.

Replace  **fieldWhichYouWant** with your requirement.